# How to determine which area is clicked in a complex image map?

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic

We are given a rather complex image map, like the one linked below. Except that the layout, shapes of each booth are more irregular, and we have lots of image maps to process.

[image]

The requirement is that the software is able to detect which booth (the boxes) is being clicked on. Once having identified the booth, we have to fetch its ID and do some processing. So we need a way to map the physical data on the map to its logical counterpart.

Usually, there are two ways I would approach the problem.

1. Pragmatically determine where the hotspot are - however in this case, there is no consistency in the layout of booths - some are a small rectangle, some are a squares
2. Manually figure out the coordinates of each booth and program it into a giant lookup. This is very time consuming, considering the number of booths (the image below is not from the project - it's just a demo). There's an estimate of at least 5000 booths spread across different maps.

Besides the two usual methods of creating hotspots for an image map, what other ways could I use to determine which booth is being clicked?

Platform used is LimeJS, but this problem should be generic enough...

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the map into booths using flood-fills, a new color for each region. You want to flood a known "corridor" spot first to eliminate that. `0,0` should work for that on most maps, I'd imagine.

This would create the hotspots you need. To cope with the print inside the boxes messing with the fill, you can just use the far corners of each region to create a rectangle. This assumes the booths are actually rectangular on the map, of course. For L-shaped booths, a little extra work might be necessary.

To get the ID from each booth, you can feed each region(from above) into an OCR, but you'll have to be able to distinguish between the ID numbers and the dimensions, etc.

Comment: I think they could also keep track of the areas flood filled, in this way they can categorize the hotspots based on size.